# Characteristic of a field such that $x^4=x$ for any $x \in X$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $K$ be a field such that $x^4=x$ for any $x \in K$. Which is its characteristic?

Well, in view of our assumption, I have $x^3=1$ for each $x \in K^*$. How can this information help me?

Moreover, may I generalize the statement taking as hypothesis the condition  $x^n=x$, with $n$ generic?

Comment: $x^3=1$ for each $x \in K^*$ means that the polynomial $X^3-1$ has at least as many roots as the elements of $K^*$. It follows that $|K^*| \leq 3$, thus $|K|$ is $2$, $3$ or $4$. If it’s not $3$, the characteristic is $2$. If it’s $3$, then $K$ is $\mathbb{F}_3$ and in that field $2^4 \neq 2$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $(-1)^4 = -1$, we get $1 = -1$, so $2=0$. The characteristic is $2$.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $X^4-X$ cannot have more than $4$ roots, but must have all elements of $K$ as root. We conclude that $K$ is finite and has at most $4$ elements. This leaves us with $\Bbb F_2$, $\Bbb F_3$, and $\Bbb F_4$. Which of these really have the desired property?